# How can I write Left Join Clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, left-join

I have MySQL query like below

```
   SELECT AVG(COALESCE(ratings.rating_for_manager, 0)), consultants.id 
   FROM consultants
   LEFT JOIN ratings ON ratings.consultant_id = consultants.id
   GROUP BY  consultants.id
```

How can I write above MySQL join query in laravel Left Join Clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `leftJoin`:

```
DB::table('consultants')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(COALESCE(ratings.rating_for_manager, 0)), consultants.id ')
    ->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.consultant_id', 'consultants.id')
    ->groupBy('consultants.id')
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked, thank you brother.

Comment: @Manjunath Glad I could help!

Comment: Ok, I'll do that for sure, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table('consultants')
 ->leftJoin('ratings','consultants.id','=','ratings.consultant_id')
->groupBy('consultant.id')->get();
```

Comment: Adding some explanation about why and how this solves the problem will much help the person who asked the question. As is, it may or may not be the correct answer, but doesn't much help understanding why.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$rslt = DB::table('consultants')
    ->leftJoin('ratings','consultants.id','=','ratings.consultant_id')
    ->select('consultants.id',DB::raw('ifnull(AVG(ratings.rating_for_manager),0) as ratingsDetails'))
         ->groupBy('consultants.id')
         ->get();
```